# Facebook Tab not loading

Tags: php, html, facebook, fbml

so i created a facebook app (fbml).

canvas url = `http://mydomain.com/fb/canvas/`

tab url = `tab.html`

i authenticated my app with my profile and added the tab to my profile. but the tab keeps loading and loading. sometimes i also get redirected to my profile page after a short tab loading time

[image]

trying to access my canvas page `http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/` works fine. also trying to access my tab page (which must be realtive to canvas) works with the apps url `http://apps.facebook.com/app/tab.html`.

does anyone know why i cannot access my tab page via the tab of my profile? the content of `tab.html`is just a little bit of "lorem ipsum", no php, no js, no body tags, nothing, just text.

looking into web-inspector, there is a file called `tab.php` which gets queried via ajax, but the content of this file is

> for (;;);{"error":1357010,"errorSummary":"Oops","errorDescription":"Something went wrong. We're working on getting it fixed as soon as we can.","errorIsWarning":false,"silentError":0,"payload":null}

is this a facebook issue? but the problem exists the whole day now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug. We're pushing a fix today.

Comment: Bug is back? Could you confirm?

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying an absolute URL for your tab URL under your Facebook application's settings.